# IF statement being inconsistent

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheets file that has A Lot of sheets, most of them have data that's pulled from other sheets.

Let's say I have a sheet called `Team 1` that has the data for Player 1, Player 2, Player 3 etc. 
Now I want to pull the data for each Player into a different sheet, AKA pull his data from `Team 1` sheet into a new sheet called `Player 1`

I used `=FILTER` normally → `=FILTER('Team 1'!A:CC, 'Team 1'!B:B="Player 1")` 
And this works very well.. BUT I had an ingenious idea to avoid `#N/A` Error in case of the player not having any data, so I cam up with this:

```
=IF(
    EXACT(
        'Team 1'!B:B, "Player 1"),
    
    FILTER(
        'Team 1'!A:CC, 'Team 1'!B:B="Player 1"),
        
    "This Player has no data")
```

Which works well.... sometimes... 
I do not understand why this `IF` statement is inconsistent.

Let's say `Player 1` has data in `Team 1` and I want to pull it into `Player 1` sheet.

If I put the formula in Row 2, it returns False:
[image]

But if I put the formula in Row 3 it returns True:
[image]

Also another weird thing, it used to work well if I put the formula in row 2 in one of the sheets but not the others.

I do not understand why any of this happened as it makes no sense.. to me at least.

***Edit1***:
I didn't enclude the `Team 1` sheet which was important as my problem wasn't with the `IF` per se, but my problem was with `EXACT`.

Apparently `EXACT` depends on the campared data to be on the same row/cell
If we put the same formula in `A1` to `A4` in `Player 1` Sheet:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the N/A error in case of an empty output, wrap the FILTER() in an IFERROR() or IFNA()

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Team 1'!A:CC, 'Team 1'!B:B="Player 1"), "This Player has no data")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you! this works well, I found my my problem to be with `EXACT` as it checks if the data is in the same row or not rather than If the data is in the column at all.